# анотация NotImplemented

Tags: java

Пытаюсь вставить в XLSX строку. Читаю доки  https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#shiftRows-int-int-int-
метод shiftRows отмечен как NotImplemented. Соответственно в рантайме какие бы я параметры не вводил у  shiftRows падаю в исключение NotImplemented.

Файл я получаю от праймфеса... долго объясянять, она попадает в функцию как Object document, конвертируем его в SXSSFWorkbook и вроде все ок.

```
 public void postProcessXLSX(Object document) {
        SXSSFWorkbook wb = (SXSSFWorkbook) document;
        SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        sheet.shiftRows(0,1,1);
    }
```

Comment: а где, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: что значит NotImplemented? правильно ли я понимаю, что это значит что функции собственно и нет, может будет, а может и нет, добавлена что было и нефиг ей пользоваться? Это я уже почитал доки внимательней, и пронял как описал выше.

Comment: ну так посмотрите [имплементацию метода](https://github.com/lvweiwolf/poi-3.16/blob/master/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.java#L987) - вы там увидите `throw new RuntimeException("Not Implemented");`